# Difference between two different ways of 2D array initialisations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I was solving one Dynamic Programming problem ([Link to problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/shortest-path-algorithms/practice-problems/algorithm/shortest-path-revisited-9e1091ea/)) in python. I initialise a 2D DP array in two different ways, and I get different outputs for both of them. Surprisingly, both of the initialisations produce same array, but the final outputs are different. I make sure that both of the initialisations produce same arrays using assert statement.

Two different ways in which I initialise the 2D arrays are as follows :

```
# method 1
dp = [[float('inf') for _ in range(k+1)]for _ in range(n+1)]

# method 2
dp1 = [[float('inf')]*(k+1)]*(n+1)

assert(dp == dp1)
```

For the following two snippets, I get two different outputs as follows. The only difference between these two code snippets is line `dp = [[float('inf') for _ in range(k+1)]for _ in range(n+1)]` in one snippet, while `dp = [[float('inf')]*(k+1)]*(n+1)` in other one.

Code 1 ([Link to this snippet and output (click on run to get output)](https://onecompiler.com/python/3wvzpdb4v)):

```
# Write your code here
import sys
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop ,heappushpop


n,m,k = map(int, input().split())
graph = {u : [] for u in range(n+1)}

for _ in range(m):
    u,v,w = map(int, input().split())
    graph[u].append((v, w))
    graph[v].append((u,w))

dp = [[float('inf') for _ in range(k+1)]for _ in range(n+1)]

# print("DP1 : ", dp)
dp[1] = [0]*(k+1)
# print("DP2 : ", dp)

pq = []

heappush(pq, (0, 1, 0))

while pq:
    _, node, par = heappop(pq)

    for [next_node, w] in graph[node]:
        if next_node != par:
            for i in range(k+1):
                if (i == 0):
                    if(dp[next_node][i] > dp[node][i] + w):
                        dp[next_node][i] = dp[node][i] + w
                        heappush(pq, (min(dp[next_node]), next_node, node))
                else:
                    if dp[next_node][i] > dp[node][i-1] or dp[next_node][i] > dp[node][i] + w:
                        dp[next_node][i] = min(dp[node][i-1], dp[node][i] + w)
                        heappush(pq, (min(dp[next_node]), next_node, node))

# print("DP3 : ", dp)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(min(dp[i]),end=" ")
print()
```

Input 1 :

```
5 6 1
1 2 2
1 3 6
2 4 6
2 5 8
3 5 4
4 5 1
```

output 1 :

```
0 0 0 2 2
```

Code 2 ([Link to this snippet and output (click on run to get output)](https://onecompiler.com/python/3wvzpkvx8))

```
# Write your code here
import sys
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop ,heappushpop


n,m,k = map(int, input().split())
graph = {u : [] for u in range(n+1)}

for _ in range(m):
    u,v,w = map(int, input().split())
    graph[u].append((v, w))
    graph[v].append((u,w))

dp = [[float('inf')]*(k+1)]*(n+1)
# temp = dp
# dp = dp1

# print("DP1 : ", dp)
dp[1] = [0]*(k+1)
# print("DP2 : ", dp)

pq = []

heappush(pq, (0, 1, 0))

while pq:
    _, node, par = heappop(pq)

    for [next_node, w] in graph[node]:
        if next_node != par:
            for i in range(k+1):
                if (i == 0):
                    if(dp[next_node][i] > dp[node][i] + w):
                        dp[next_node][i] = dp[node][i] + w
                        heappush(pq, (min(dp[next_node]), next_node, node))
                else:
                    if dp[next_node][i] > dp[node][i-1] or dp[next_node][i] > dp[node][i] + w:
                        dp[next_node][i] = min(dp[node][i-1], dp[node][i] + w)
                        heappush(pq, (min(dp[next_node]), next_node, node))

# print("DP3 : ", dp)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(min(dp[i]),end=" ")
print()
```

Input 2 :

```
5 6 1
1 2 2
1 3 6
2 4 6
2 5 8
3 5 4
4 5 1
```

output 2 :

```
0 0 0 0 0
```

In the script, when I initialise two different 2d arrays using following code, and write assertion about whether or not they are the same or not, I surprisingly get that both of them are same. In that case, why am I getting different outputs for two same 2D arrays in my program, just initialised differently?

```
# This part does not produce any assertion error!
dp = [[float('inf') for _ in range(k+1)]for _ in range(n+1)]
dp1 = [[float('inf')]*(k+1)]*(n+1)
assert(dp == dp1)
```

Comment: ```dp = [[float('inf')]*(k+1)]*(n+1)``` for this case, try to do ```dp[0][0] = 5```, the result will be ```[[5, inf], [5, inf], [5, inf], [5, inf], [5, inf], [5, inf]]```. It seems like for each element in the 2nd array have the same memory locations, when you create like in the second method

Comment: Yes, good catch @SamadzadeMuhammed. I'm getting the same output you provided.